# Change the background color of b-form-checkbox-group

Tags: css, checkbox, bootstrap-vue

I am struggling to change the default (blue) on checked background color of checkbox rendered through b-form-checkbox-group. Could not find a proper way from the docs of Bootstrap-vue even if it is there.

Code looks like below:

```
<b-form-group>
  <b-form-checkbox-group
    id="checkboxId"
    v-model="anArrayInDataHook"
    :options="anArrayInDataOrComputedHook"
    name="randomName">
  </b-form-checkbox-group>
</b-form-group>
```

If it needs CSS modification, then it is fine too. Tried with different approaches but failed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the tags of the question, I am using `Bootstrap-vue` in my `VueJS`  application. The main problem was, I was trying to change the `checkbox` background by adding CSS classes and selectors within the `Vue component` that has `scoped SCSS`.

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
    //CSS here
</style>
```

That was not working as styles for `b-form-checkbox-group` were global scoped.

Solution was to add the required CSS in the Common/Main SCSS file which was global scoped as well. Following CSS changes worked for me:

```
.custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
    color: #fff;
    border-color: $green-200;
    background-color: $green-100;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following should do the work.

```
custom-control-label:after{ 
     background-color:red;  // just for sake of example.
}
```

**How to know this?**

Just inspect the element you want to modify and look for property causing this blue color.

Comment: @Suryanch Singh, thanks for your effort. I had already tried with inspecting through Chrome developer tool. However, the main issue was that the applied styles were not working no matter whatever applied on classes referenced for `<b-form-checkbox-group>`. 

I have added the answer just in case if someone else faces the same issue as mine.